# How do I assign JSON list to TypeScript Interface in Angular 4

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am working on Angular tutorial project and have created interface called IProduct and I want assign JSON list to IProduct array or object and not sure how to do it

### interface

```
export interface IProduct{
  productId: number;
  productName: string;
  productCode: string;
  releaseDate: string;
  description: string;
  price:number;
  starRating: number;
  imageUrl: string;
 }
```

### Angular Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IProduct } from './Products';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-product',
  templateUrl: './Product-List.Component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Product-list.component.css']
})

 export class ProductListComponent
  {
   PageTitle: string = "Product List";

   Products: IProduct[] = [
        {
            "productId": 1,
            "productName": "Leaf Rake",
            "productCode": "GDN-0011",
            "releaseDate": "March 19, 2016",
            "description": "Leaf rake with 48-inch wooden handle.",
            "price": 19.95,
            "starRating": 3.2,
            "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/26215/Anonymous_Leaf_Rake.png"
        },
        {
            "productId": 2,
            "productName": "Garden Cart",
            "productCode": "GDN-0023",
            "releaseDate": "March 18, 2016",
            "description": "15 gallon capacity rolling garden cart",
            "price": 32.99,
            "starRating": 4.2,
            "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/58471/garden_cart.png"
        },
        {
            "productId": 5,
            "productName": "Hammer",
            "productCode": "TBX-0048",
            "releaseDate": "May 21, 2016",
            "description": "Curved claw steel hammer",
            "price": 8.9,
            "starRating": 4.8,
            "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/73/rejon_Hammer.png"
        },
        {
            "productId": 8,
            "productName": "Saw",
            "productCode": "TBX-0022",
            "releaseDate": "May 15, 2016",
            "description": "15-inch steel blade hand saw",
            "price": 11.55,
            "starRating": 3.7,
            "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/27070/egore911_saw.png"
        },
        {
            "productId": 10,
            "productName": "Video Game Controller",
            "productCode": "GMG-0042",
            "releaseDate": "October 15, 2015",
            "description": "Standard two-button video game controller",
            "price": 35.95,
            "starRating": 4.6,
            "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/120337/xbox-controller_01.png"
        }
    ];
```

I am getting error in doing above assigning;

### Error

```
  Type '{ "productId": number; "productName": string; "productCode": string; "releaseDate": string; "desc...' is not assignable to type 'IProduct[]'.
 Type '{ "productId": number; "productName": string; "productCode": string; "releaseDate": string; "desc...' is not assignable to type 'IProduct'.
 Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"productId"' does not exist in type 'IProduct'.
```

Comment: The error message and your supplied code do not agree `Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"productId"' does not exist in type 'IProduct'.` - are you sure youve defined `productId` in your interface

Comment: yes I have defined, I have provided interface and json both above, thanks

Comment: seems to working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhu7lp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @toxic - I can see that, but you wouldnt be the first to have not included the *real* code in the question, but instead a contrived version of it without the actual error.

Comment: what you mean, I coded as above provided!

Comment: The error messages clearly don't match with the code you provided. Maybe you just forgot to save the file. Maybe you copied and pasted the wrong snippet. Maybe you're editing another file than the one you think.

Comment: ... maybe there is more than one `IProduct` in your project and you're referencing the wrong one. Maybe you made the change and forgot to get TS to retranspile. There are any number of possibilities but as a comment states above - in isolation your code works fine

Comment: this is crazy, I have close Visual Studio Code and open project again and its working!

Comment: @toxic I'm surprised with all these comments no one mentioned that there is no such thing as a JSON list in JavaScript. Well there is... But only in so much as JavaScript is a superset of JSON

Answer (score -1):

When everything correct and you still see error specifc to Type matching issues with interface during compile. Just restart VSCode it works fine.

Comment: Your solution cannot possibly work every time. It might have worked on time but if we don't look beneath the surface to see the reason why it happened we're never going to learn anything.